# How to fix "[Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted" when using AirSim unity python

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, anaconda, spyder, dji-sdk

I am trying to use unity to simulate a real world location and movement of a drone while simutaniously moving the DJI tello Drone in the real world environment.

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
    File "<ipython-input-6-6b86f3bafb33>", line 1, in <module> 
        runfile('C:/Users/fahre/Desktop/dronecontrol.py', wdir='C:/Users/fahre/Desktop')   
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
        execfile(filename, namespace)   
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 95, in execfile
        exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)   
    File "C:/Users/fahre/Desktop/dronecontrol.py", line 73, in <module>
        tellodrone = tellopy.Tello()   
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tellopy\_internal\tello.py", line 91, in __init__
        self.sock.bind(('', self.port))   
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
        return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)

error: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

some suggested that I use

```
#s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

in the tello.py source file but im not sure where to do the edit.

```
# Create a UDP socket
self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
self.sock.bind(('', self.port))
self.sock.settimeout(2.0)
```

most of my tello.py file code will be posted below

```
import threading
import socket
import time
import datetime
import struct
import sys
import os

from  import crc
from  import logger
from  import event
from  import state
from  import error
from  import video_stream
from  utils import *
from  protocol import *
from  import dispatcher

log = logger.Logger('Tello')

class Tello(object):
    EVENT_CONNECTED = event.Event('connected')
    EVENT_WIFI = event.Event('wifi')
    EVENT_LIGHT = event.Event('light')
    EVENT_FLIGHT_DATA = event.Event('fligt_data')
    EVENT_LOG = event.Event('log')
    EVENT_TIME = event.Event('time')
    EVENT_VIDEO_FRAME = event.Event('video frame')
    EVENT_VIDEO_DATA = event.Event('video data')
    EVENT_DISCONNECTED = event.Event('disconnected')
    EVENT_FILE_RECEIVED = event.Event('file received')
    # internal events
    __EVENT_CONN_REQ = event.Event('conn_req')
    __EVENT_CONN_ACK = event.Event('conn_ack')
    __EVENT_TIMEOUT = event.Event('timeout')
    __EVENT_QUIT_REQ = event.Event('quit_req')

    # for backward comaptibility
    CONNECTED_EVENT = EVENT_CONNECTED
    WIFI_EVENT = EVENT_WIFI
    LIGHT_EVENT = EVENT_LIGHT
    FLIGHT_EVENT = EVENT_FLIGHT_DATA
    LOG_EVENT = EVENT_LOG
    TIME_EVENT = EVENT_TIME
    VIDEO_FRAME_EVENT = EVENT_VIDEO_FRAME

    STATE_DISCONNECTED = state.State('disconnected')
    STATE_CONNECTING = state.State('connecting')
    STATE_CONNECTED = state.State('connected')
    STATE_QUIT = state.State('quit')

    LOG_ERROR = logger.LOG_ERROR
    LOG_WARN = logger.LOG_WARN
    LOG_INFO = logger.LOG_INFO
    LOG_DEBUG = logger.LOG_DEBUG
    LOG_ALL = logger.LOG_ALL

    def __init__(self, port=9000):
        self.tello_addr = ('192.168.10.1', 8889)
        self.debug = False
        self.pkt_seq_num = 0x01e4
        self.port = port
        self.udpsize = 2000
        self.left_x = 0.0
        self.left_y = 0.0
        self.right_x = 0.0
        self.right_y = 0.0
        self.sock = None
        self.state = self.STATE_DISCONNECTED
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.connected = threading.Event()
        self.video_enabled = False
        self.prev_video_data_time = None
        self.video_data_size = 0
        self.video_data_loss = 0
        self.log = log
        self.exposure = 0
        self.video_encoder_rate = 4
        self.video_stream = None
        self.wifi_strength = 0

        # video zoom state
        self.zoom = False

        # File recieve state.
        self.file_recv = {}  # Map filenum -> protocol.DownloadedFile
        #s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        # Create a UDP socket
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.sock.bind(('', self.port))
        self.sock.settimeout(2.0)

        dispatcher.connect(self.__state_machine, dispatcher.signal.All)
        threading.Thread(target=self.__recv_thread).start()
        threading.Thread(target=self.__video_thread).start()

    def set_loglevel(self, level):
        """
        Set_loglevel controls the output messages. Valid levels are
        LOG_ERROR, LOG_WARN, LOG_INFO, LOG_DEBUG and LOG_ALL.
        """
        log.set_level(level)

    def get_video_stream(self):
        """
        Get_video_stream is used to prepare buffer object which receive video data from the drone.
        """
        newly_created = False
        self.lock.acquire()
        log.info('get video stream')
        try:
            if self.video_stream is None:
                self.video_stream = video_stream.VideoStream(self)
                newly_created = True
            res = self.video_stream
        finally:
            self.lock.release()
        if newly_created:
            self.__send_exposure()
            self.__send_video_encoder_rate()
            self.start_video()

        return res

    def connect(self):
        """Connect is used to send the initial connection request to the drone."""
        self.__publish(event=self.__EVENT_CONN_REQ)

    def wait_for_connection(self, timeout=None):
        """Wait_for_connection will block until the connection is established."""
        if not self.connected.wait(timeout):
            raise error.TelloError('timeout')

    def __send_conn_req(self):
        port = 9617
        port0 = (int(port/1000) % 10) << 4 | (int(port/100) % 10)
        port1 = (int(port/10) % 10) << 4 | (int(port/1) % 10)
        buf = 'conn_req:%c%c' % (chr(port0), chr(port1))
        log.info('send connection request (cmd="%s%02x%02x")' % (str(buf[:-2]), port0, port1))
        return self.send_packet(Packet(buf))

    def subscribe(self, signal, handler):
        """Subscribe a event such as EVENT_CONNECTED, EVENT_FLIGHT_DATA, EVENT_VIDEO_FRAME and so on."""
        dispatcher.connect(handler, signal)

    def __publish(self, event, data=None, **args):
        args.update({'data': data})
        if 'signal' in args:
            del args['signal']
        if 'sender' in args:
            del args['sender']
        log.debug('publish signal=%s, args=%s' % (event, args))
        dispatcher.send(event, sender=self, **args)

    def takeoff(self):
        """Takeoff tells the drones to liftoff and start flying."""
        log.info('set altitude limit 30m')
        pkt = Packet(SET_ALT_LIMIT_CMD)
        pkt.add_byte(0x1e)  # 30m
        pkt.add_byte(0x00)
        self.send_packet(pkt)
        log.info('takeoff (cmd=0x%02x seq=0x%04x)' % (TAKEOFF_CMD, self.pkt_seq_num))
        pkt = Packet(TAKEOFF_CMD)
        pkt.fixup()
        return self.send_packet(pkt)

    def land(self):
        """Land tells the drone to come in for landing."""
        log.info('land (cmd=0x%02x seq=0x%04x)' % (LAND_CMD, self.pkt_seq_num))
        pkt = Packet(LAND_CMD)
        pkt.add_byte(0x00)
        pkt.fixup()
        return self.send_packet(pkt)

    def palm_land(self):
        """Tells the drone to wait for a hand underneath it and then land."""
        log.info('palmland (cmd=0x%02x seq=0x%04x)' % (PALM_LAND_CMD, self.pkt_seq_num))
        pkt = Packet(PALM_LAND_CMD)
        pkt.add_byte(0x00)
        pkt.fixup()
        return self.send_packet(pkt)

    def quit(self):
        """Quit stops the internal threads."""
        log.info('quit')
        self.__publish(event=self.__EVENT_QUIT_REQ)

    def __send_time_command(self):
        log.info('send_time (cmd=0x%02x seq=0x%04x)' % (TIME_CMD, self.pkt_seq_num))
        pkt = Packet(TIME_CMD, 0x50)
        pkt.add_byte(0)
        pkt.add_time()
        pkt.fixup()
        return self.send_packet(pkt)

    def __send_start_video(self):
        pkt = Packet(VIDEO_START_CMD, 0x60)
        pkt.fixup()
        return self.send_packet(pkt)

    def __send_video_mode(self, mode):
        pkt = Packet(VIDEO_MODE_CMD)
        pkt.add_byte(mode)
        pkt.fixup()
        return self.send_packet(pkt)

    def set_video_mode(self, zoom=False):
        """Tell the drone whether to capture 960x720 4:3 video, or 1280x720 16:9 zoomed video.
        4:3 has a wider field of view (both vertically and horizontally), 16:9 is crisper."""
        log.info('set video mode zoom=%s (cmd=0x%02x seq=0x%04x)' % (
            zoom, VIDEO_START_CMD, self.pkt_seq_num))
        self.zoom = zoom
        return self.__send_video_mode(int(zoom))

    def start_video(self):
        """Start_video tells the drone to send start info (SPS/PPS) for video stream."""
        log.info('start video (cmd=0x%02x seq=0x%04x)' % (VIDEO_START_CMD, self.pkt_seq_num))
        self.video_enabled = True
        self.__send_exposure()
        self.__send_video_encoder_rate()
        return self.__send_start_video()

    def set_exposure(self, level):
        """Set_exposure sets the drone camera exposure level. Valid levels are 0, 1, and 2."""
        if level < 0 or 2 < level:
            raise error.TelloError('Invalid exposure level')
        log.info('set exposure (cmd=0x%02x seq=0x%04x)' % (EXPOSURE_CMD, self.pkt_seq_num))
        self.exposure = level
        return self.__send_exposure()

    def __send_exposure(self):
        pkt = Packet(EXPOSURE_CMD, 0x48)
        pkt.add_byte(self.exposure)
        pkt.fixup()
        return self.send_packet(pkt)

    def set_video_encoder_rate(self, rate):
        """Set_video_encoder_rate sets the drone video encoder rate."""
        log.info('set video encoder rate (cmd=0x%02x seq=%04x)' %
                 (VIDEO_ENCODER_RATE_CMD, self.pkt_seq_num))
        self.video_encoder_rate = rate
        return self.__send_video_encoder_rate()

    def __send_video_encoder_rate(self):
        pkt = Packet(VIDEO_ENCODER_RATE_CMD, 0x68)
        pkt.add_byte(self.video_encoder_rate)
        pkt.fixup()
        return self.send_packet(pkt)

    def take_picture(self):
        log.info('take picture')
        return self.send_packet_data(TAKE_PICTURE_COMMAND, type=0x68)

    def up(self, val):
        """Up tells the drone to ascend. Pass in an int from 0-100."""
        log.info('up(val=%d)' % val)
        self.left_y = val / 100.0

    def down(self, val):
        """Down tells the drone to descend. Pass in an int from 0-100."""
        log.info('down(val=%d)' % val)
        self.left_y = val / 100.0 * -1

    def forward(self, val):
        """Forward tells the drone to go forward. Pass in an int from 0-100."""
        log.info('forward(val=%d)' % val)
        self.right_y = val / 100.0

    def backward(self, val):
        """Backward tells the drone to go in reverse. Pass in an int from 0-100."""
        log.info('backward(val=%d)' % val)
        self.right_y = val / 100.0 * -1

    def right(self, val):
        """Right tells the drone to go right. Pass in an int from 0-100."""
        log.info('right(val=%d)' % val)
        self.right_x = val / 100.0

    def left(self, val):
        """Left tells the drone to go left. Pass in an int from 0-100."""
        log.info('left(val=%d)' % val)
        self.right_x = val / 100.0 * -1

    def clockwise(self, val):
        """
        Clockwise tells the drone to rotate in a clockwise direction.
        Pass in an int from 0-100.
        """
        log.info('clockwise(val=%d)' % val)
        self.left_x = val / 100.0

    def counter_clockwise(self, val):
        """
        CounterClockwise tells the drone to rotate in a counter-clockwise direction.
        Pass in an int from 0-100.
        """
        log.info('counter_clockwise(val=%d)' % val)
        self.left_x = val / 100.0 * -1

    def flip_forward(self):
        """flip_forward tells the drone to perform a forwards flip"""
        log.info('flip_forward (cmd=0x%02x seq=0x%04x)' % (FLIP_CMD, self.pkt_seq_num))
        pkt = Packet(FLIP_CMD, 0x70)
        pkt.add_byte(FlipFront)
        pkt.fixup()
        return self.send_packet(pkt)

    def flip_back(self):
        """flip_back tells the drone to perform a backwards flip"""
        log.info('flip_back (cmd=0x%02x seq=0x%04x)' % (FLIP_CMD, self.pkt_seq_num))
        pkt = Packet(FLIP_CMD, 0x70)
        pkt.add_byte(FlipBack)
        pkt.fixup()
        return self.send_packet(pkt)

    def flip_right(self):
        """flip_right tells the drone to perform a right flip"""
        log.info('flip_right (cmd=0x%02x seq=0x%04x)' % (FLIP_CMD, self.pkt_seq_num))
        pkt = Packet(FLIP_CMD, 0x70)
        pkt.add_byte(FlipRight)
        pkt.fixup()
        return self.send_packet(pkt)

    def flip_left(self):
        """flip_left tells the drone to perform a left flip"""
        log.info('flip_left (cmd=0x%02x seq=0x%04x)' % (FLIP_CMD, self.pkt_seq_num))
        pkt = Packet(FLIP_CMD, 0x70)
        pkt.add_byte(FlipLeft)
        pkt.fixup()
        return self.send_packet(pkt)

    def flip_forwardleft(self):
        """flip_forwardleft tells the drone to perform a forwards left flip"""
        log.info('flip_forwardleft (cmd=0x%02x seq=0x%04x)' % (FLIP_CMD, self.pkt_seq_num))
        pkt = Packet(FLIP_CMD, 0x70)
        pkt.add_byte(FlipForwardLeft)
        pkt.fixup()
        return self.send_packet(pkt)

    def flip_backleft(self):
        """flip_backleft tells the drone to perform a backwards left flip"""
        log.info('flip_backleft (cmd=0x%02x seq=0x%04x)' % (FLIP_CMD, self.pkt_seq_num))
        pkt = Packet(FLIP_CMD, 0x70)
        pkt.add_byte(FlipBackLeft)
        pkt.fixup()
        return self.send_packet(pkt)

    def flip_forwardright(self):
        """flip_forwardright tells the drone to perform a forwards right flip"""
        log.info('flip_forwardright (cmd=0x%02x seq=0x%04x)' % (FLIP_CMD, self.pkt_seq_num))
        pkt = Packet(FLIP_CMD, 0x70)
        pkt.add_byte(FlipForwardRight)
        pkt.fixup()
        return self.send_packet(pkt)

    def flip_backright(self):
        """flip_backleft tells the drone to perform a backwards right flip"""
        log.info('flip_backright (cmd=0x%02x seq=0x%04x)' % (FLIP_CMD, self.pkt_seq_num))
        pkt = Packet(FLIP_CMD, 0x70)
        pkt.add_byte(FlipBackLeft)
        pkt.fixup()
        return self.send_packet(pkt)

    def __fix_range(self, val, min=-1.0, max=1.0):
        if val < min:
            val = min
        elif val > max:
            val = max
        return val

    def set_throttle(self, throttle):
        """
        Set_throttle controls the vertical up and down motion of the drone.
        Pass in an int from -1.0 ~ 1.0. (positive value means upward)
        """
        if self.left_y != self.__fix_range(throttle):
            log.info('set_throttle(val=%4.2f)' % throttle)
        self.left_y = self.__fix_range(throttle)

    def set_yaw(self, yaw):
        """
        Set_yaw controls the left and right rotation of the drone.
        Pass in an int from -1.0 ~ 1.0. (positive value will make the drone turn to the right)
        """
        if self.left_x != self.__fix_range(yaw):
            log.info('set_yaw(val=%4.2f)' % yaw)
        self.left_x = self.__fix_range(yaw)

    def set_pitch(self, pitch):
        """
        Set_pitch controls the forward and backward tilt of the drone.
        Pass in an int from -1.0 ~ 1.0. (positive value will make the drone move forward)
        """
        if self.right_y != self.__fix_range(pitch):
            log.info('set_pitch(val=%4.2f)' % pitch)
        self.right_y = self.__fix_range(pitch)

    def set_roll(self, roll):
        """
        Set_roll controls the the side to side tilt of the drone.
        Pass in an int from -1.0 ~ 1.0. (positive value will make the drone move to the right)
        """
        if self.right_x != self.__fix_range(roll):
            log.info('set_roll(val=%4.2f)' % roll)
        self.right_x = self.__fix_range(roll)

    def __send_stick_command(self):
        pkt = Packet(STICK_CMD, 0x60)

        axis1 = int(1024 + 660.0 * self.right_x) & 0x7ff
        axis2 = int(1024 + 660.0 * self.right_y) & 0x7ff
        axis3 = int(1024 + 660.0 * self.left_y) & 0x7ff
        axis4 = int(1024 + 660.0 * self.left_x) & 0x7ff
        '''
        11 bits (-1024 ~ +1023) x 4 axis = 44 bits
        44 bits will be packed in to 6 bytes (48 bits)

                    axis4      axis3      axis2      axis1
             |          |          |          |          |
                 4         3         2         1         0
        98765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210
         |       |       |       |       |       |       |
             byte5   byte4   byte3   byte2   byte1   byte0
        '''
        log.debug("stick command: yaw=%4d thr=%4d pit=%4d rol=%4d" %
                  (axis4, axis3, axis2, axis1))
        log.debug("stick command: yaw=%04x thr=%04x pit=%04x rol=%04x" %
                  (axis4, axis3, axis2, axis1))
        pkt.add_byte(((axis2 << 11 | axis1) >> 0) & 0xff)
        pkt.add_byte(((axis2 << 11 | axis1) >> 8) & 0xff)
        pkt.add_byte(((axis3 << 11 | axis2) >> 5) & 0xff)
        pkt.add_byte(((axis4 << 11 | axis3) >> 2) & 0xff)
        pkt.add_byte(((axis4 << 11 | axis3) >> 10) & 0xff)
        pkt.add_byte(((axis4 << 11 | axis3) >> 18) & 0xff)
        pkt.add_time()
        pkt.fixup()
        log.debug("stick command: %s" % byte_to_hexstring(pkt.get_buffer()))
        return self.send_packet(pkt)

    def send_packet(self, pkt):
        """Send_packet is used to send a command packet to the drone."""
        try:
            cmd = pkt.get_buffer()
            self.sock.sendto(cmd, self.tello_addr)
            log.debug("send_packet: %s" % byte_to_hexstring(cmd))
        except socket.error as err:
            if self.state == self.STATE_CONNECTED:
                log.error("send_packet: %s" % str(err))
            else:
                log.info("send_packet: %s" % str(err))
            return False

        return True

    def send_packet_data(self, command, type=0x68, payload=[]):
        pkt = Packet(command, type, payload)
        pkt.fixup()
        return self.send_packet(pkt)

    def __process_packet(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, str):
            data = bytearray([x for x in data])

        if str(data[0:9]) == 'conn_ack:' or data[0:9] == b'conn_ack:':
            log.info('connected. (port=%2x%2x)' % (data[9], data[10]))
            log.debug('    %s' % byte_to_hexstring(data))
            if self.video_enabled:
                self.__send_exposure()
                self.__send_video_encoder_rate()
                self.__send_start_video()
            self.__publish(self.__EVENT_CONN_ACK, data)

            return True

        if data[0] != START_OF_PACKET:
            log.info('start of packet != %02x (%02x) (ignored)' % (START_OF_PACKET, data[0]))
            log.info('    %s' % byte_to_hexstring(data))
            log.info('    %s' % str(map(chr, data))[1:-1])
            return False

        pkt = Packet(data)
        cmd = uint16(data[5], data[6])
        if cmd == LOG_MSG:
            log.debug("recv: log: %s" % byte_to_hexstring(data[9:]))
            self.__publish(event=self.EVENT_LOG, data=data[9:])
        elif cmd == WIFI_MSG:
            log.debug("recv: wifi: %s" % byte_to_hexstring(data[9:]))
            self.wifi_strength = data[9]
            self.__publish(event=self.EVENT_WIFI, data=data[9:])
        elif cmd == LIGHT_MSG:
            log.debug("recv: light: %s" % byte_to_hexstring(data[9:]))
            self.__publish(event=self.EVENT_LIGHT, data=data[9:])
        elif cmd == FLIGHT_MSG:
            flight_data = FlightData(data[9:])
            flight_data.wifi_strength = self.wifi_strength
            log.debug("recv: flight data: %s" % str(flight_data))
            self.__publish(event=self.EVENT_FLIGHT_DATA, data=flight_data)
        elif cmd == TIME_CMD:
            log.debug("recv: time data: %s" % byte_to_hexstring(data))
            self.__publish(event=self.EVENT_TIME, data=data[7:9])
        elif cmd in (TAKEOFF_CMD, LAND_CMD, VIDEO_START_CMD, VIDEO_ENCODER_RATE_CMD, PALM_LAND_CMD,
                     EXPOSURE_CMD):
            log.info("recv: ack: cmd=0x%02x seq=0x%04x %s" %
                     (uint16(data[5], data[6]), uint16(data[7], data[8]), byte_to_hexstring(data)))
        elif cmd == TELLO_CMD_FILE_SIZE:
            # Drone is about to send us a file. Get ready.
            # N.b. one of the fields in the packet is a file ID; by demuxing
            # based on file ID we can receive multiple files at once. This
            # code doesn't support that yet, though, so don't take one photo
            # while another is still being received.
            log.info("recv: file size: %s" % byte_to_hexstring(data))
            if len(pkt.get_data()) >= 7:
                (size, filenum) = struct.unpack('<xLH', pkt.get_data())
                log.info('      file size: num=%d bytes=%d' % (filenum, size))
                # Initialize file download state.
                self.file_recv[filenum] = DownloadedFile(filenum, size)
            else:
                # We always seem to get two files, one with most of the payload missing.
                # Not sure what the second one is for.
                log.warn('      file size: payload too small: %s' % byte_to_hexstring(pkt.get_data()))
            # Ack the packet.
            self.send_packet(pkt)
        elif cmd == TELLO_CMD_FILE_DATA:
            # log.info("recv: file data: %s" % byte_to_hexstring(data[9:21]))
            # Drone is sending us a fragment of a file it told us to prepare
            # for earlier.
            self.recv_file_data(pkt.get_data())
        else:
            log.info('unknown packet: %04x %s' % (cmd, byte_to_hexstring(data)))
            return False

        return True

    def recv_file_data(self, data):
        (filenum,chunk,fragment,size) = struct.unpack('<HLLH', data[0:12])
        file = self.file_recv.get(filenum, None)

        # Preconditions.
        if file is None:
            return

        if file.recvFragment(chunk, fragment, size, data[12:12+size]):
            # Did this complete a chunk? Ack the chunk so the drone won't
            # re-send it.
            self.send_packet_data(TELLO_CMD_FILE_DATA, type=0x50,
                payload=struct.pack('<BHL', 0, filenum, chunk))

        if file.done():
            # We have the whole file! First, send a normal ack with the first
            # byte set to 1 to indicate file completion.
            self.send_packet_data(TELLO_CMD_FILE_DATA, type=0x50,
                payload=struct.pack('<BHL', 1, filenum, chunk))
            # Then send the FILE_COMPLETE packed separately telling it how
            # large we thought the file was.
            self.send_packet_data(TELLO_CMD_FILE_COMPLETE, type=0x48,
                payload=struct.pack('<HL', filenum, file.size))
            # Inform subscribers that we have a file and clean up.
            self.__publish(event=self.EVENT_FILE_RECEIVED, data=file.data())
            del self.file_recv[filenum]

    def __state_machine(self, event, sender, data, **args):
        self.lock.acquire()
        cur_state = self.state
        event_connected = False
        event_disconnected = False
        log.debug('event %s in state %s' % (str(event), str(self.state)))

        if self.state == self.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
            if event == self.__EVENT_CONN_REQ:
                self.__send_conn_req()
                self.state = self.STATE_CONNECTING
            elif event == self.__EVENT_QUIT_REQ:
                self.state = self.STATE_QUIT
                event_disconnected = True
                self.video_enabled = False

        elif self.state == self.STATE_CONNECTING:
            if event == self.__EVENT_CONN_ACK:
                self.state = self.STATE_CONNECTED
                event_connected = True
                # send time
                self.__send_time_command()
            elif event == self.__EVENT_TIMEOUT:
                self.__send_conn_req()
            elif event == self.__EVENT_QUIT_REQ:
                self.state = self.STATE_QUIT

        elif self.state == self.STATE_CONNECTED:
            if event == self.__EVENT_TIMEOUT:
                self.__send_conn_req()
                self.state = self.STATE_CONNECTING
                event_disconnected = True
                self.video_enabled = False
            elif event == self.__EVENT_QUIT_REQ:
                self.state = self.STATE_QUIT
                event_disconnected = True
                self.video_enabled = False

        elif self.state == self.STATE_QUIT:
            pass

        if cur_state != self.state:
            log.info('state transit %s -> %s' % (cur_state, self.state))
        self.lock.release()

        if event_connected:
            self.__publish(event=self.EVENT_CONNECTED, **args)
            self.connected.set()
        if event_disconnected:
            self.__publish(event=self.EVENT_DISCONNECTED, **args)
            self.connected.clear()

    def __recv_thread(self):
        sock = self.sock

        while self.state != self.STATE_QUIT:

            if self.state == self.STATE_CONNECTED:
                self.__send_stick_command()  # ignore errors

            try:
                data, server = sock.recvfrom(self.udpsize)
                log.debug("recv: %s" % byte_to_hexstring(data))
                self.__process_packet(data)
            except socket.timeout as ex:
                if self.state == self.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    log.error('recv: timeout')
                self.__publish(event=self.__EVENT_TIMEOUT)
            except Exception as ex:
                log.error('recv: %s' % str(ex))
                show_exception(ex)

        log.info('exit from the recv thread.')

    def __video_thread(self):
        log.info('start video thread')
        # Create a UDP socket
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        port = 6038
        sock.bind(('', port))
        sock.settimeout(5.0)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 512 * 1024)
        log.info('video receive buffer size = %d' %
                 sock.getsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF))

        prev_video_data = None
        prev_ts = None
        history = []
        while self.state != self.STATE_QUIT:
            if not self.video_enabled:
                time.sleep(1.0)
                continue
            try:
                data, server = sock.recvfrom(self.udpsize)
                now = datetime.datetime.now()
                log.debug("video recv: %s %d bytes" % (byte_to_hexstring(data[0:2]), len(data)))
                show_history = False
```

Comment: Could you explain how exactly this is related to unity? so far I can only see a huge python script ...

Comment: I am using the unity AirSim plugin for simulation and this python code controls a unity drone model.